# GAE multiple WSGI files for multiple URL handlers

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, wsgi

I'm having problems understanding how I would use Google App Engine URL handler mapping to map URLs to various files. Here's the code I currently have:

**app.yaml**

```
handlers:
- url: /
script: main.app
- url: /blog/*
  script: blog.app
```

**end of main.py** (MainPage handler does exist towards top)

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

**end of blog.py** (BlogPage and New Post exist towards top)

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/blog', BlogPage), ('/blog/newpost', NewPost)], debug=True)
```

So right now, if I go to `http://127.0.0.1/` my MainPage handler will pick it up like it's supposed to. But, if I go to `http://127.0.0.1/blog/` then I end up getting a 404. I can't figure out if it's the handler in my blog.py file that's messing up, or if I need to have the handlers defined in app.yaml changed.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was no match for the URI you're requesting, i.e. /blob/.  Note that you have the extra '/' at the end.  If you want that to be handled by BlogPage, you can use the following ...

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/blog/?', BlogPage), ('/blog/newpost', NewPost)], debug=True)
```

/blog/? will match either /blog or /blog/.

Hope that helps.